Disable pdflatex calls when building R-4.3.3
I'm currently trying to build one of the latest R -> 4.3.3. I'm installing it as an EasyBuild module, however that isn't really the issue here.
The thing is that during configuration, it automatically picks up an available pdflatex version on that system (check details below), which for some reason causes the process to crash with this error:
building/updating vignettes for package 'parallel' ...
building/updating vignettes for package 'utils' ...
building/updating vignettes for package 'stats' ...
processing 'reshape.Rnw'                                                                                          
Error: compiling TeX file 'reshape.tex' failed with message:                                                            
unable to run pdflatex on 'reshape.tex'
LaTeX errors:
! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 

pdflatex --version :
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11

Online answers suggest to either update texlive, or to install the texlive-fonts-extra package. Now, this can be somehow troublesome on this system, so I would like to find a way to directly disable the pdflatex calls during the config/build processes for R, so this vignettes step is skipped.
I've tried adding the following flags to the config phase, however they seem to do nothing:
--with-docs=no --with-vignettes=no --with-manual=no --with-build-vignettes=no

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

I found that you need to edit the .eb file and change line
R CMD Rd2pdf --quiet --force --no-clean $R_DOC_DIR/man $R_DOC_DIR/html
into
R CMD Rd2pdf --quiet --force --no-clean --pdf=no $R_DOC_DIR/man $R_DOC_DIR/html
to avoid the use of PDF and use HTML only for documentation. What I am not sure about is if the --pdf=no flag would work if used during building process.
Following this guide

When setting the flag --pdf=no to the configopts, it fails to recognise it:
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --pdfdir: no

I guess the flag is OK, but no the denying option. Trying with --pdf=FALSE is also not recognised.

Did you ever solve this issue? I seem to have run into this as well. Adding --pdf=no or --with-docs=no --with-vignettes=no --with-manual=no --with-build-vignettes=no with the ./configure doesn't help. My pdflatex --version states this pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) kpathsea version 6.3.2 Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37 Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11 Compiled with xpdf version 4.02. In the end make still produces the same error as you have... Should we try rebuilding pdflatex.

I didn't, actually. I just pointed to some resources that could help.

I worked around it by:
yum remove texlive-latex
cd R-4.4.2
./configure
make

As you see, this essentially disable PDF and Tex builds.
